# Envío de texto de un JFrame a otro

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Quisiera saber por qué este codigo no me envía datos de un Jframe a otro. Tengo dos campos (textField), uno (num1) en un Jframe llamado compras y el otro (p4) en otro Jframe llamado factura.

Lo que quiero es que yo digite cualquier palabra en el campo de compras llamado num1 y me aparezca en el otro campo (p4) del otro JFrame.

Para eso ejecuto el siguiente código, en un botón llamado factura, como se muestra a continuación. Pero no envía la palabra.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

```
private void BotonFacturaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){             
    String dato; //variable que gusrda la informacion que se dijite el JTextField llamado num1
    dato=num1.getText();//estoy capturando lo que se digite en el campo num1 y guardandolo en la variable dato
    new Factura().setVisible(true);//la ventana que recibe los datos se abra
    Factura.p4.setText(dato);//envia el dato a la variable de la factura
}
```

Comment: 1) Informatica se trata de comunicación de informaciones. 2) puntuación es parte integral de la comunicación. 3) El lenguaje en que estas trabajando es Java, no Netbeans, Netbeans solamente es tu IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando necesito enviar información entre ventanas suelo modificar el constructor del JFrame agregando el parámetro la variable que deseo enviar.

Ejemplo.
En mi ventana principal, evento al hacer clic al boton:

```
private void btnSendTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String nombre = txtNombre.getText(); //Obtengo el texto que contiene el textfield txtNombre

    JFrame childFrame = new ChildFrame(nombre); //Creo una instancia de mi otra ventana "childFrame"
    childFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Que cuando aparezca la ventana sea en el centro de la pantalla principal
    childFrame.setResizable(false); //Que no se pueda cambiar el tamaño
    childFrame.setVisible(true); //Que sea visible
}
```

Ahora, puedes notar que al crear la instancia del childFrame, estoy enviando por parámetro la variable "nombre" al metodo constructor. Del otro lado se ve de esta forma.

En la otra ventana, en el método constructor:

```
public ChildFrame(String arg) {
    initComponents(); //Metodo que inicializa los componentes generados por netbeans
    lblSaludo.setText("Hola: "+arg); //Establezco a mi lblSaludo el texto
}
```

Existen otras formas de hacer esto, también puedes crear una función "init" propia y después de instanciar la ventana hija, llamas a su método init y le envías las variables que sean requeridas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en el Jframe compra tienes tu campo de texto y tu boton

```
private javax.swing.JButton btnEnviar;
private javax.swing.JTextField num1;
```

dentro del actionPerformed

```
int info = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
    Factura.dato = info;
    Factura f = new Factura();
    f.setVisible(true);
```

el Jframe factura tiene una variable estatica usada para setear ese valor en este formulario

```
public static int dato;
```

en tu contructor haces esto

```
public Factura() {
    initComponents();

    //se modifica el valor del campo de texto p4
    //al momento de crear una nueva instancia de Factura esto sucedara cuando se precione el boton en tu ventana compra se modifica dicha variable y luego se setea en este campos de texto
    p4.setText(Integer.toString(dato));

}
```